# How can I assign command output to a variable in GNU make target rule?

Tags: gnu-make, sh

At a BASH prompt, I can do the following:

```
~/repo$ HISTORY_LOG=$(git log $(get_old_version)..$(get_new_version)); [[ ! -z ${HISTOR_LOG} ]] && ( echo "Some header"; echo "${HISTORY_LOG}" )
```

Where `git log` is demonstrably simplified version of what I actually have.

In a make file I have the following command as part of a target:

```
$(OUTPUT): $(INPUT)
        ...
        echo "Some header" > $(LOG_FILE)
        git log $(shell get_old_version)..$(shell get_new_version) >> $(LOG_FILE)
```

**How can I rewrite the make target to behave like the bash command?**

If I do the following line-feeds are being stripped:

```
$(OUTPUT): $(INPUT)
        ...
        HISTORY_LOG="$(shell git log $(shell get_old_version)..$(shell get_new_version))" ; \
           [ -z "$${HISTORY_LOG}" ] && \
             true || \ 
             (echo "Some header" ; echo "$${HISTORY_LOG}" )
```

when run looks like:

```
~/repo $ make
commit 2b4d87b0e64d129028c1a7a0b46ccde2f42c5e93     Author: Jamie   <Jamie@mymail.com>   Date:   Mon Jun 25 18:46:27 2012 -0400              Issue #468: This sucker's been sped up.
```

and what I prefer would be:

```
~/repo $ make
commit 2b4d87b0e64d129028c1a7a0b46ccde2f42c5e93     
Author: Jamie   <Jamie@mymail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 25 18:46:27 2012 -0400 

    Issue #468: This sucker's been sped up.
```

I think the issue is the that `make` executes commands in `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`.   Regardless I'm looking for a portable solution if there is one.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to assign the output to a variable? Note that the variable passes out of scope at the end of the command.

Comment: Because I want to add a preamble only if the output is non-empty.  The command generating the output is a bit unwieldy, I don't want to put it in the make file twice.  And the fact the variable passes out of scope at the end of the command is desirable.  An edit shows the a header is also printed if the output is non-empty.

Comment: GNUMake allows you to choose the shell, but not being a shell expert I'd probably just store the output in a temporary file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make's `shell` is eating your newlines.  Just stop using it.  Instead of `$( shell get_old_version )`, escape the `$`:

```
$$( get_old_version )
```

Comment: The escaping idea worked; but the spot you picked wasn't the culprit it was the `$(shell git log ...)` that needed the `$$(git log ...) ` treatment.  Thanks.